# toggleClass does not add class for the first time & works further

Tags: javascript, jquery

when clicking for the first time the `toggleclass()` does not add selected class, but after that it works smoothly

HTML:

```
<li class="categories col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center pb20 pointer" id="1" onclick="categories(this.id)">
  <img src="some-image" class="registerCategory">
Rice
</li>
```

JS:

```
var taken1 = [];
function categories(c_id)  {

    $("li.categories").click(function(e1) {
        e1.preventDefault();            
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        e1.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    var inp = document.getElementById("categories");
    var ind = taken1.indexOf(c_id);

    if(ind > -1){
        taken1.splice(ind,1);
        taken1 = taken1;
    } else {
        taken1.push(c_id);
    }
    inp.value = taken1.join(',');
}
```

Comment: Can you show your html as well?

Comment: <li class="categories col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center pb20 pointer" id="1" onclick="categories(this.id)"><img src="some-image" class="registerCategory">Rice</li>

Comment: We do not have a crystal ball to guess your entire code/mark-up . Please share all necessary code and create a working example of your problem

Comment: In addition to HTML please provide your CSS

Comment: .selected {
                background-color: #7bf29f;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

Comment: It is a good practice to add the code into your original question, pasting it with code formatting for easier read.

Comment: this was my first question here...thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event was getting bound after first click.bind `click` event outside of your function.

```js
var taken1 = [];
$("li.categories").click(function(e1) {
        e1.preventDefault();            
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        e1.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
function categories(c_id)  {    

    var inp = document.getElementById("categories");
    var ind = taken1.indexOf(c_id);

    if(ind > -1){
        taken1.splice(ind,1);
        taken1 = taken1;
    } else {
        taken1.push(c_id);
    }
    inp.value = taken1.join(',');
}
```

```css
.selected { background-color: #7bf29f; border-radius: 50%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="categories col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center pb20 pointer" id="1"><img src="some-image" class="registerCategory">Rice</li>
```

Comment: it is working perfectly fine, but i tried to implement it on other class named "categories2" there selected class is not toggled

Comment: You might need to bind the click event on that element as well.

Comment: when i was creating a fiddle for the same, it is working , in my code it is not working

Comment: That I can not check!Because I am not having you code nor the fiddle!

Comment: So you are saying, this code is not working in your code?If so, can you post you proper code so that I can verify.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BozwEXPY6jJwA0W8PeuH0NP_x_s6pqo5srxAwu1b1d0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can u suggest why the above code is not working for other classes?

Answer (score 1):

Problem arises as you are attaching the event handler inside the `click` handler.

Bind event handler outside the function `categories()`

```
$("li.categories").click(function (e1) {
    e1.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    e1.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

function categories(c_id) {
    //relevant code
}
```

---

However as you are binding event get rid of inline click handler and remove `onclick="categories(this.id)"`

```
<li class="categories col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-center pb20 pointer" id="1" ><img src="some-image" class="registerCategory">Rice</li>
```

*Script*

```
$("li.categories").click(function (e1) {
    e1.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    e1.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //Call the function from event handler
    categories(this.id);
});
```